# Omnistudio - Omniscript - PDF Action and PDF Template

Tags: pdf, vlocity, omnistudio

We are trying to get a list of accounts records using a DR in omniscript. Is it possible to dynamically display account records dynamically using the PDF Action and PDF template? For example, if I have 30 account records in a query, the pdf will display all 30 accounts with certain fields. But if I only have 15 accounts in the query, it will only display 15 accounts.

Answer (score 0):

In Vlocity OmniScript you will find "PDF Action" in Action Set. This is used to generate the PDFs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create a DR in which you will fetch account details.
Step 2:
In Omniscript build search PDF action in that you can select DR type as Transform and Output type as PDF.
Step 3:
Then in that PDF Action, scroll down to send transformation % add the DR from where you're mapping the account details with PDF value.